# how to remove the substring in shellscript

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have the String like

```
something0^^^something1^^^something2^^^something3
```

I want Only String

```
something0^^^something1^^^something2
```

by removing

```
^^^something3
```

How can i get it in shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure BASH:

```
s='something0^^^something1^^^something2^^^something3'
echo "${s/^^^something3/}"
something0^^^something1^^^something2
```

OR you can just delete everything after last `^^^`:

```
echo "${s%^^^*}"
something0^^^something1^^^something2
```

Comment: Why make in complicate when `bash` can do it :) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\^\^\^something3//g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\^\^\^/,",");NF-=1}1' OFS="^^^"
something0^^^something1^^^something2
```

Fixed by changing `FS` to some else

---

Another version

```
awk '{sub(/\^\^\^[^\^]*$/,x)}1' file
something0^^^something1^^^something2
```

Comment: sorry sir i don't know the value of something3 it can vary

Comment: I believe OP wants: `something0^^^something1^^^something2`

Comment: @anubhava I know and has also written that in my post that I have problem with `^` as FS.  Can you tell me how to use `^` as FS correctly?

Comment: Ya sure sure let me try this awk.

Comment: @anubhava Found a working `awk` but still nice to know how to handle `^` as `FS`

Comment: @Jotne: Try this one: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\^\\^\\^"; OFS="^^^"} {NF-=1}1' file`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, see my updated answer, seems to work to.  Seem to need the `BEGIN` block for `FS` to accept `\\`

Comment: Yes because of caret signs `FS` and `OFS` are separate and `FS=OFS=...` would'nt work. `sub function` will work fine.